# Yii2 ajax валидация и сценарии

Tags: php, yii2, валидация

Есть `actionCreate`, в форме прописана отдельная ссылка на ajax валидацию, т.е.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'enableClientValidation' => false,
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl' => '/item/validate',
    ]); ?>
```

В `actionCreate` контроллера `ItemController` прописан сценарий `insert`

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Item([
        'scenario' => 'insert'
    ]);
}
```

И `actionValidate`

```
public function actionValidate()
{
    if ( Yii::$app->request->isAjax )
    {
        $model = new Item(); // получить здесь сценарий или текущую модель

        if ( $model->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) )
        {
            if ( $errors = ActiveForm::validate( $model ) )
            {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return $errors;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос, как заставить валидацию работать по сценарию, т.е. в данном случае `insert` ?

Comment: $model->setScenario ?

Comment: Не понял. Сценарии то разные, а экшн валидации один, в этом собственно и проблема. Т.е. сценарии разные быть могут.

Comment: Тогда нужно каким-то образом передавать сценарий. Возможно, просто сделать hidden input или что то вроде.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/**
 * @param integer $id
 * @return array
 */
public function actionAjaxValidate($id = null)
{
    $model = $id ? $this->findModel($id) : new Item(['scenario' => 'insert']);
    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```